# Sequelize cannot connect to postgres server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database with Sequelize. When I try to create a row in the database, I get the following error message. I'm not sure why the port is listing 3306 when the database url I'm trying to connect to is port 5432. I tried setting the port and host name in the config file, but I still get the same error.

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeConnectionRefusedError",
    "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306",
    "parent": {
        "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 3306,
        "fatal": true
    },
    "original": {
        "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 3306,
        "fatal": true
    }
}
```

I'm running my app in my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


// INSTANTIATE EXPRESS APP
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  type: function() {
    return true
  }
}))

// SET VIEW ENGINE
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

require('./src/server/routes')(app)

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

// SET FOLDER TO SERVER STATIC ASSETS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, username")
  //and remove cacheing so we get the most recent comments
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});

// SERVER APP
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server running on localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

my config file is set up to use an online database

```
{
  "development": {
    "url": "postgres://database@stampy.db.elephantsql.com:5432/znjpptuy",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "PORT": 5432,
    "HOST": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After closer inspection, realized that the error had to do with the url I was passing to the new instance of sequelize, in this case, lack of url.

sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.url]);

process.env kept coming back as undefined so I ended up passing the actual url to the function.